# Read CF environment nested JSON with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, configuration-files

I have an application on SpringBoot that is deployes to Cloud Foundry. It has a bound service that attaches some information to VCAP_SERVICES that I can use in my application.properties file to receive security related data.

This services variables are in the `user-provided` sub-json of whole VCAP_SERVICE environment variable and looks like this:

```
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "auth-scopes": {
      "group-1": "superadmin",
      "group-2": "admin"
     },
     "base64ClientCredential": "SSBBTSBOT1QgVEhBVCBTSUxMWSA6LUQ=",
     "client-id": "my-app",
     "client-secret": "g1234567890",
     "token-info-uri": "https://XYZ.predix.io/check_token",
     "user-info-uri": "https://XYZ.predix.io/userinfo"
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "my-app-creds",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
```

In my application.properties I have

```
security.properties.client-id=${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.client-id}
security.properties.client-secret=${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.client-secret}
security.properties.token-info-uri=${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.token-info-uri}
security.properties.user-info-uri=${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.user-info-uri}
security.properties.auth-scopes=${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.auth-scopes}
```

I also created class `SecurityProperties` that reads those properties and stores in JAVA:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security.properties")
public class SecurityProperties {

    String clientId;
    String clientSecret;
    String tokenInfoUri;
    String userInfoUri;

    //Required getters and setters
}
```

And this class successfully binds those fields to information received from `application.properties`.

The problem occurs when I want to receive Map:

```
 "auth-scopes": {
  "group-1": "superadmin",
  "group-2": "admin"
 }
```

I tried adding to `SecurityProperties` class field:

```
HashMap<String, String> authScopes;
```

But it fails

I also tried with inner class

```
AuthScopes authScopes;

public static class AuthScopes {
    //various different implementations
    //to read this but no success at all
}
```

I ran out of other ideas. I just can't figure out how to get this. I will also accept that `auth-scopes` json from `VCAPS` will be read as a string, and then I will parse it - no problem. The issue is that even if I add to `SecurityProperties` field `String authScopes` it is bound with exactly this string: `"${vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.auth-scopes}"`. Nothing useful.

If you have any idea - please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot provides the `vcap.` properties via the [CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html). That class reads the `VCAP_SERVICES` JSON and flattens it into a set of discrete properties. If you add [Spring Boot actuators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-enabling) to your application and access the `/env` endpoint, you will see the set of `vcap.` properties that get created.

In your example, the properties will contain these values:

```
"vcap": {
  ...
  "vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.auth-scopes.group-1": "******",
  "vcap.services.my-app-creds.credentials.auth-scopes.group-2": "******",
}
```

There is no `vcap.services.my-service.credentials.auth-scopes` property in that list, because the JSON get completely flattened. The property names use the dot notation to reflect the JSON structure, but the hierarchy is not preserved in the set of properties. In short, what you are trying to do won't work with Boot properties.

One alternative would be to set those values as a string instead of a hash in the JSON, as in `"auth-scopes": "group-1:superadmin,group-2:admin"` or `"auth-scopes": "group-1=superadmin,group-2=admin"`. Your `SecurityProperties` could then get the value of `vcap.services.my-service.credentials.auth-scopes` and parse the String into a Map.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is what I was afraid of. I think that I will reverse the vcap and create property that is a list (which i already checked and it worked) of groups that bare given authority.